# What Happens To A Process When Memory-Mapped Data Can't Asynchronously Flush To Disk?

Tags: linux, memory-mapped-files

I have a program that maps a writable file into memory.  Because this file is extended via `ftruncate` to its maximum size, it starts out empty and sparse.  It's thus possible that writing to it via memory can SIGBUS if the disk is full and it's impossible for the OS to realize the file and cover the accessed memory range.  Annoying, but [manageable](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/?id=41da295eb50fa08eaacd0ecde99f43a716fcb41a).

*What happens to the process if the file is successfully extended and the blocks are mapped and the memory writes are completed... **but** an I/O error prevents the OS from* asynchronously *flushing the page to disk?*

Comment: Have you considered testing it yourself? I think you could build something using the device mapper, that produces IO errors reliably.

Comment: Considered, yes, but I didn't know how to simulate such an error.

Comment: There is an example on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/498900/intentionally-cause-an-i-o-error-in-linux/498931